# ckeditor error: TypeError: b.lang.contextmenu is undefined

Tags: ckeditor

I'm getting headaches with resolving the following CK Editor error:

```
TypeError: b.lang.contextmenu is undefined
```

I've downloaded the latest version of Ck Editor (4.3.4). The old version 4.2 used to work fine.

Ck Editor will cause error in both Firefox and Chrome. I tried clearing the cache, downloading the compressed and uncompressed (as said to be a resolution in some cases) version as well as defining CKEDITOR_BASEPATH path.

I also tried removing contextmenu plugin, without success.

Does anyone have the idea why is that happening?

Thanks for help

Comment: Could you upload somewhere a CKEditor package with which you have problem?

Comment: @alijaz did u get any solutions

Comment: @ddw147 not really.. I switched back to old CkEditor, too many issues with the new one

Comment: @Aljaz i too switch to other version , i think some files were missing. thanks anyway

Comment: I have this same problem - 4 years later...

Comment: I found out the problem has to do with incorrect language detection: https://csharpin.blogspot.com/2011/08/ckeditor-mlangcontextmenu-is-undefined.html